# Is 'closing as not constructive' valid behavior?

Tags: discussion

I've seen this many times

> closed as not constructive by AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD, EEE yesterday
>
> As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A
>   format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or
>   specific expertise, **but this question will likely solicit debate,
>   arguments, polling, or extended discussion**.

and it's always bugged me.  Aren't you blaming the victim for the crime?

Comment: How so? Are we blaming the asker for not looking at the FAQ or bothering to find out what is and isn't suitable? Sure. Do you honestly think that's a problem?

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/

Comment: Depends on who you consider to be the victim... The victim could just as easily be the site or the people who have to take the time to clean it up...

Comment: Closed as not constructive, eh?  :-) Suppose I should've expected it, really!  :-)

Comment: When someone asks a question like "Which is better: Python or Perl?", are you saying that it's not their fault that answers will be about comparing Python and Perl?

Answer (score 3):

The person writing the question is not the victim, but the perpetrator. He/she writes a question which is not considered to be of the correct format. The StackExchange sites have a narrowly defined goal, to be question and answer sites, not a forum where open ended questions are ok.

The people of SE have made a decision what they want to do with the site, and it is working very well within that goal (asking concrete question, getting concrete objective answers). This goal, and the concequences it has for which questions are a good fit or not, are well explained in the FAQ.

So I don't really see your point, other than that you wished the site was something different than it is.

Comment: If you're suggesting no-one should challenge the rules, then that implies you think the site is perfect.  Do you?  I don't.  I think it's very good.  It's often my first port-of-call.  But there are aspects of it I don't like at all.  For example, I hate that people can downvote without being recorded.  I hate that people do downvote without admitting it and giving a reason.  I find it cowardly to do it anonymously and unhelpful not to give a reason.

Comment: People can challenge the rules, and some challenges here on meta turn into real features. This of course heavily depends on how the people of StackExchange and the community thinks about it. The amount of downvotes suggests that the community does not generally share your sentiment.

Answer (score 2):

> Aren't you blaming the victim for the crime?

Well, no. Answers are only valid in the context created by the question. That is to say, if your question is likely to invite answers (and possibly lots of them) which can be seen as debates, arguments, responses to a poll, discussions, etc. then the answers are not at fault, but the question is.

That is also why the argument "but I only want answers which are supported by facts, references, or specific expertise" doesn't work. What you might want is not always what your question is likely to invite.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing we blame on the OP (original poster of the question) is not taking a look at the *How to ask question* and *What question should I ask* sections of the FAQ (as clearly explained in the message).